# warning "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sqlite

```
NSString *titl = [database executeNonQuery:@"SELECT * FROM numberquestion"];
```

gives warning:

> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

What is wrong?

Table "numberquestion" contains only one string "twenty" of type TEXT

Comment: what type your database is? how executeNonQuery is declared?..

Comment: Presumably you are using some Objective-C wrapper framework for your database.  Pleas amend your question to state which one.

Comment: In the .NET framework, a similarly named function returns the *number of affected rows*, not the actual result of the (ahem) query. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris this one is quiet similar to .net thanks it helped me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `database` object seems to return an `int` on `executeNonQuery:@"SELECT * FROM numberquestion"`.

If its some sort of generic database accessor I would expect an array or a similar structure as result for a “SELECT * …”.

But as the method reads “executeNonQuery:” it maybe only returns a state (encoded in an integer), because you don't expect a result (exectute**Non**Query).

Comment: Almost certainly an integer status is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake Got the answer. executeQuery in place of executeNonQuery  should be used